# Why does a fuse break before an LED?

Tags: current, resistance, fuses

[image]

Assuming the current passing is more than what both the fuse and the LED can handle, if electrons pass through the bulb first, would the fuse break first, or is it a matter of the LED requiring more time before breaking or could it actually happen, therefore rendering the use of a fuse in the location pictured useless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fuses are rated by current.  LEDs are also rated by current.

The order of the parts in the circuit you showed doesn't matter.  Whether the fuse blows first or the LED explodes first depends on the construction of the fuse and the LED.

A fast blow fuse rated for the same current as the LED will (probably) blow before the LED explodes - or maybe not.  It doesn't really matter.

A slow blow fuse would (probably) not blow before the LED burns out - or you get "lucky" and your LED can conduct a lot of current for long enough that the fuse does blow first.

The point of a fuse is **not** to protect the components in your circuit.

The fuse is there to prevent a short circuit from starting a fire.

You pick a fuse that is rated to pass a bit more than you expect your circuit to draw.  If your circuit has a short in it somewhere, the fuse will blow and prevent overheated components from drawing current for long enough to start a fire.

If you are lucky, the fuse will blow before any of the components are damaged.  If not, well, it doesn't matter.  The fuse was there to prevent a fire, not protect your components.

Components may or may not burn out and go open circuit when they break.  Some will fail short circuit and continue conducting current until the power source is removed.  The fuse is there to remove power in such conditions.

---

The one exception you might find are "crowbar" circuits.  These are designed such that an incorrect operating condition in the circuit deliberately causes a short to blow the fuse.  These are often used as reverse polarity protection or as over voltage protection.

Answer (score 2):

Protecting semiconductors with a fuse is generally not so easy. Fuses are better at protecting wiring and such like from causing a fire. In the case of a small LED and a fat fuse, the LED might well be permanently damaged (shorted, say) before the fuse opens. Or the very thin wire bond in a typical indicator LED might fuse before the fuse opens and the LED will protect the fuse from blowing. If you look at a water-clear LED closely you'll typically see a hair-thin wire (about 25 microns in diameter) between the top of the LED die and the lead frame.

In many cases, we don't care so much about the semiconductor dying, what we care about is safety (no fires or excessive smoke) so a properly sized fuse is cheap and very reliable for what it does.

There's a set of fuse characteristics called \$\text I^2\text t\$ which are particularly appropriate to protection of power semiconductors. You can read more about it in [this](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/automotive/catalogs/littelfuse_fuseology.pdf) application note. Except for power semiconductors you'll not likely find a matching characteristic for semiconductors though, so sizing a fuse is not easy, if it's even possible to find a fuse that allows the circuit to work and still will protect.

Semiconductors are relatively fragile electrically compared to switches, wires, relay contacts etc.  So in cases where the user may cause problems, the first line of protection would generally be electronic and then perhaps a fuse for safety reasons. For example, we could place this circuit together with the LED:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYBeSH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now even if the user connects the unit with the incorrect polarity or to an incorrect voltage (within upper design limits) the LED is protected. You may also add a series fuse to protect the wiring in case the electronics fails.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does a fuse break before an LED?

A fuse does not always break before the LED. What if a timed fuse instead of a fast-acting one is used? Would the result be the same?

In the shown diagram, even if the battery's output resistance may act as a limiter resistor (also its resistance will increase because of excessive heat, but let's ignore that), the LED may get damage but may not break down that fast.

Of course, there's a current limit for the LED's p-n junction can handle, but the fuse's I²t rating also plays a role here. So it may not be that easy to forecast what will break down first.

Answer (score 0):

What causes both the LED and the fuse to fail is heat.  That takes time to build up. Specifically for fuses though, their current rating is not a precise threshold that makes them act like a switch, melting right above the threshold but operating forever just below it.

The image below is a typical set of curves that specify the "Fusing time", i.e., how long for a fuse to fail under different current values.  Each blue line is for a specific fuse rating.  So for example, if you take a fuse rated at 0.25A, notice that if 0.5A pass through it, it will take almost 0.2 seconds before it blows.  Also notice that at 0.4A, it will take much longer than 10 seconds to blow.  Some fuses are rated "fast-blow", meaning they tend to fail faster than "slow-blow" type, but you will still have to deal with a time delay.

So specific to your question, which fails first, the LED or the fuse, depends heavily on the fuse rating and the maximum current that the LED can handle.  Most small LEDs are rated at 20mA and depending on the brand of 9V battery, you are likely to see over 1Amp flowing as there is no resistance in the circuit other than the battery's own internal resistance.  So more likely than not, the use of a fuse in that circuit is indeed useless and the LED will likely blow first; if it shorts, then the fuse will also blow!

[image]

Comment: Expept that's not a 9V battery.  It is a hypothetical 20V battery connected to a hypothetical 9V LED.  There's no telling what current a 9V LED is rated for.  :)

Comment: 9V vs 20V doesn't really change much of the analysis of what is going on.  Still, not enough information...